# Word for level of centralized-ness

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a `-ness`-like word that describes how centralised something is (say, a bee colony).

That is, a very centralised bee colony would have a very condensed hive, and a very decentralised colony might even be geographically disparate.

Example: "Level of centralizedness: very decentralized"

- Does this word exist?

Comment: "centripetality"

Comment: Mixing roots throws people so don't put 'ness' on a Latinate word, when a Latin form exists: Centralization is a better form, and might capture most of what you mean.  Concentration literally means "how much something has (is with) a(/its) center", but it is now a very secondary meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Level of [centralization](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/centralization)" is, I think, the most obvious option, although I think I prefer *"degree of centralization"* in most instances.